# SQL optional NULL value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't have more than 1 sql string.

I have an element that is optional (#element). If not specified, I want to get anything from the column `oper_cd_id_principal` (which contains NULL values).

If specified, I could use

```
select * from Table
where oper_cd_id_principal like #element
```

This would bring the result I want.
But, if #element is not specified , I can use '%' as #element. It would bring me all values EXCEPT NULL values

I've seen

```
select * from Table
where (oper_cd_id_principal like #element OR oper_cd_id_principal IS NULL)
```

In this example, if #element is not specified it would return the result I need it.
But if is specified it would bring me the `oper_cd_id_principal = #element` and all other null values from `oper_cd_id_principal`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a variation of your code

where oper_cd_id_principal = #element or
(oper_cd_id_principal is null and #element is null)

to

where oper_cd_id_principal like #element OR
(oper_cd_id_principal is null and #element = '%')

If element is specified it brings me only the result where column = element. OR is ignored

If element is not specified, i can transform the null value from #element into '%'.
So this part (oper_cd_id_principal like #element) brings me every line where oper_cd_id_principal is not NULL and the OR part brings me every NULL line

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select *
from Table
where oper_cd_id_principal like #element OR
      (#element = '%' and oper_cd_id_principal IS NULL)
```

Or possibly:

```
where coalesce(oper_cd_id_principal, ' ') like #element
```

You need to be careful because the default value could accidentally match some strings.

EDIT:

Based on your edit, you might want:

```
where oper_cd_id_principal = #element or
      (oper_cd_id_principal is null and #element is null)
```

Comment: If is specified a value for #element i want only results that oper_cd_id_principa = #element

Comment: @AlexLanes . . . I don't understand.  Your question is using `like`, not `=`.